# Jquery Sortable and mouseenter problem

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, mouseenter

I have **sortable** divs and in this divs - paragraphs.
If I use **mouseenter** event to check if the mouse is in this divs - it doesn't work.
I.e
Sortable + mouseenter on the sortable elements = doesn't work.
How can I fix it?

Here you are some code

```
$("#sort").click(function() {



            $("#ps").sortable();
            $("#ps").disableSelection();


    });
```

When click on div with id sort - the divs in #ps become sortable.

```
<div id="ps" style="border:1px solid red;">
<div class="happy" style="border:1px solid red;width:100px;">
<p>
dasdasdasdas
</p> 
</div>
<div class="happy" style="border:1px solid red;width:100px;">
<p>
1234
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

And

```
$(".happy").mouseenter(function() {
    alert("OK");
});
```

Comment: Some code would help us a little bit here.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".happy").live('mouseover',function() {
 alert("OK");
});
```

This is the solution.

P.S
This problem occurs also with click and hover events.